# Two queries mysql in one object json

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, object

I have two tables that I want to convert them to json like this:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2013-07-20",
      "id":"123456",
      "year":"2013",
      "people":[
         {
            "name":"First",
            "age":"60",
            "city":"1"
         },
         {
            "name":"second",
            "age":"40",
            "city":"2"
         },
         {
            "name":"third",
            "age":"36",
            "city":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

but the result of my code is this:

```
[
   {
      "date":"2013-07-20",
      "id":"123456",
      "year":"2013",}
      ,{
      "people":[
         {
            "name":"First",
            "age":"60",
            "city":"1"
         },
         {
            "name":"second",
            "age":"40",
            "city":"2"
         },
         {
            "name":"third",
            "age":"36",
            "city":"1"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

the code creates a new object to the array "people" and I want that are in the same object

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data where id='123456'");
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT name,age,city FROM people where id='123456'"); 

$json = array();
$json2['people'] = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = $row;
  }

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
    $row_temp["name"]=$row["name"];
    $row_temp["age"] = $row["age"];
    $row_temp["city"] = $row["city"];

   array_push($json2['people'],$row_temp);
   }

    array_push($json, $json2);

echo Json_encode($json);
```

How I can make the array is in the same object as the table "data"?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data where id='123456'");
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT name,age,city FROM people where id='123456'"); 

// I think, you'll get a single row, so no need to loop
$json = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

$json2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
    $json2[] = array( 
        'name' => $row["name"],
        'age' => $row["age"],
        'city' => $row["city"]
    );
}
$json['people'] = $json2;
echo json_encode($json);
```

Result of `print_r($json)` should be something like this

```
Array
(
    [date] => 2013-07-20
    [year] => 2013
    [id] => 123456
    [people] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => First
                    [age] => 60
                    [city] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => second
                    [age] => 40
                    [city] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Result of `echo json_encode($json)` should be

```
{
    "date" : "2013-07-20",
    "year":"2013",
    "id":"123456",
    "people":
    [
        {
            "name" : "First",
            "age" : "60",
            "city" : "1"
        },
        {
            "name" : "second",
            "age" : "40",
            "city" : "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you do `echo json_encode(array($json))` then you will get your whole `json` wrapped in an array, something like this

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2013-07-20",
        "year":"2013",
        "id":"123456",
        "people":
        [
            {
                "name" : "First",
                "age" : "60",
                "city" : "1"
            },
            {
                "name" : "second",
                "age" : "40",
                "city" : "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried the three examples all have responded and returned the same code. 
{
   "0":{
      "date":"2013-07-20",
      "id":"123456",
      "year":"2013"
   },
      "people":[....]
}
   
I want it to be like this
[
   {
      "date":"2013-07-20",
      "id":"123456",
      "year":"2013",
      "people":[......] 
 }
]
You know how to correct it? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe, you should post your query results then.

Comment: You mean the result of the query in the database or json encoded?

Comment: Results of both querys, not json.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM data where id='123456'

date      year id
2013-07-20 2013 123456

SELECT name,age,city FROM people where id='123456'

name age   city  id
First 60   1  123456
second 40   2  123456
city 36   1  123456
`
Sorry for the format

Answer (score 0):

You were very close, but you want the People array to be a direct value of the outer array and you've wrapped it in an extra array.

Also, please note that the MySQL library you are using is deprecated. That means it will be removed from PHP in a future release. You should replace calls from the MySQL_* family of functions with either [mysqli](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [pdo](http://php.net/pdo)

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data where id='123456'");
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT name,age,city FROM people where id='123456'"); 

$json = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = $row;
  }

$json['people'] = array();

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
    $row_temp["name"]=$row["name"];
    $row_temp["age"] = $row["age"];
    $row_temp["city"] = $row["city"];

   array_push($json['people'],$row_temp);
   }

echo Json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by waiting to use the key `people` until the very end when you join the two arrays. Up until then, just load the data into `$json` and `$json2`.

```
$json = array('date' => '2013', 'id' => '123456', 'year' => '2013');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data where id='123456'");
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT name,age,city FROM people where id='123456'"); 

$json = array();
$json2 = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = $row;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch)){
    $row_temp["name"]=$row["name"];
    $row_temp["age"] = $row["age"];
    $row_temp["city"] = $row["city"];
    array_push($json2, $row_temp);
}

$json['people'] = $json2;

echo Json_encode($json);
```