# Two MySQL queries in JSON objects

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to build the following JSON through MySQL and PHP.
Each Chapter has an id, a chapter title, and a list of topics.
Each topic has an id and a topic area

```
{
"Chapters": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "chapterTitle": "Introduction",
        "Topics": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "topicArea": "C++"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "topicArea": "Java"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "chapterTitle": "Getting Started",
        "Topics": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "topicArea": "Start Here"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

However, I am not able to generate this output if I try the following PHP code ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911533/two-queries-mysql-in-one-object-json))

```
//Get all chapters
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chapters");      

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $json[] = $row;
    $json2 = array();
    $chapterid = $row["id"];

    //Fetch all topics within the first book chapter
    $fetch = mysql_query("SELECT id,topicArea FROM topics where chapterid=$chapterid");
    while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
    {
         $json2[] = array( 
            'id' => $row2["id"],
            'topicArea' => $row2["topicArea"]
           );
     }
     $json['Topics'] = $json2;          //I think the problem is here!
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Comment: Look into SQL injection and SQL parameters to fix it.

Comment: `$json['Topics'][] = $json2;`   otherwise get overwritten

Comment: You're telling us that something is wrong, but you're not telling us what you get as a result instead. We need to see that in order to do more than point out logical flaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions any more. Both `mysqli` and `PDO` enables you to use prepared statements.

With that said, you are right that `$json['Topics'] = $json2;` is the problem: this needs to be `$json['Topics'][] = $json2;`.

Finally for performance reasons (look at [What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)), you might want to look into a `JOIN`. All in all:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
$query = 'SELECT c.id AS chapter_id, c.chapterTitle, t.id as topic_id, t.topicArea FROM chapters c INNER JOIN topics t ON c.id = t.chapterid';
$json = array();
foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {
  $json[$row['chapter_id']]['id'] = $row->chapter_id;
  $json[$row['chapter_id']]['chapter_title'] = $row->chapter_title;
  $json[$row['chapter_id']]['Topics'][] = array(
    'id' => $row->topic_id,
    'topicArea' => $row->topicArea,
  );
}
print json_encode(array_values($json));
```