# Having two queries in one JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I am trying to Select everything from two tables and display them through JSON. Here is my shot at trying that:

```
 <?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "****", "user");

if ($conn->connect_error) {

 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
 // Getting the received JSON into $json variable.
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

 // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
 $obj = json_decode($json,true);

// Populate Username from JSON $obj array and store into $usnername.
$username = $_GET['username'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE username = '$username'";
$usql = "SELECT * FROM user_images  WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = $conn->query($sql, $usql);

if ($result->num_rows >0) {


 while($row[] = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

 $tem = $row;

 $json = json_encode($tem);


 }

} else {
 echo  "No Results Found.";
}
 echo $json;
$conn->close();
?>
```

I am not too sure if this is the correct way to achieve my task, but I looked at other questions and none are in the same format as mine. Also, I know this is vulnerable to SQL injections, this is just for example purposes.

users Table:

-id -username -profilepic

1       Bill      image.png

2        Sally     cats.png

user_images table:

-id -username -posts

1        Bill           Food

2          Bill        Sports

3         Sally         Coffee

Comment: First of all you can't pass two queries in a single call to `$conn->query()`. The second parameter is `$resultmode` and is used to pass certain options for the query execution.
But to really help you, we need to know: What would you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I want to display some user info such as a profile picture and display all of the user's post. And I can't really use `JOIN` because that will display the profile picture multiple times. @TobiasXy

Answer (score 3):

I know you mentioned it in your question, but it bears repeating- this is vulnerable to SQL injections because you are referencing user input from the `$_GET` array directly in your SQL query without first sanitizing it or, better, using prepared statements.

`$result = $conn->query($sql, $usql);`
The [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function takes a single query, and an optional `MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT` parameter which you are incorrectly specifying by passing the second SQL statement, `$usql`- so this will not work.

Instead, you should perform a `JOIN` on the two tables in the same query. So, combining your queries would look something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users 
LEFT JOIN user_images ON user_images.username = user.username 
WHERE username = '$username'";
```

Or, as a prepared statement:

```
$prepared_statement = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users LEFT JOIN user_images ON user_images.username = user.username WHERE username = ?");
$prepared_statement->bind_param("s", $username);
$result = $prepared_statement->execute();
```

This will combine the information contained in the two tables so that you can pull the relevant information out in a single loop. Additionally you might consider gathering only the relevant information for your response, so you are not sending back an entire user object via JSON.

*Edit* After considering new information provided, it may be best to do the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE username = '$username'";
$usql = "SELECT * FROM user_images  WHERE username = '$username'";

$users_result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($users_result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($user = $users_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $posts_array = array();
        $posts_result = $conn->query($usql);
        if ($posts_result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($post = $posts_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $posts_array[] = array(
                    "id" => $post['id'],
                    "post" => $post['post']
                );
            }
        }
        $response = array(
            "id" => $user['id'],
            "username" => $user['username'],
            "profilepic" => $user['profilepic'],
            "posts" => $posts_array
        );
        $json = json_encode($response);
        echo $json;
    }
} else {
    echo  "No Results Found.";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Thank you, but the thing about `JOIN` is that it will display all the user posts and include say the profile picture depending on how ever many posts. I'm trying to achieve something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911533/two-queries-mysql-in-one-object-json @Jesse

Comment: Basically, where it does display all user posts(`user_images`), but it will display a profile picture once. (`users`)

Comment: Unless you've got a strange DB schema, I'm not following on how tables `users` and `user_images` contain user posts- I'm assuming this is for something like a messaging application, forum software, or comments section? To me, `users` would contain a singular entry for each user in your database and `user_images` would contain a singular profile picture (or multiple pictures with one defined as the "primary"). If your goal is to get a list of posts with attached user information, start with whatever your `posts` table is and `JOIN` user info onto that.

Comment: I updated my code. Maybe I can try using `JOIN`. Is there a way to limit a row, because the row of `users` will echo everytime a user have a post. So say if a user have 10 posts, they would see their information(username,email,password, etc.) 10 times. @Jesse

Comment: If that's the case then it may be better to keep your two queries as-is and execute them separately. First, gather a list of `users`. Then, loop over the results of that query and begin building an array based off of that. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: I tried out your code, and all the results came out null. This seems like it should work

Comment: My bad, take the `[]` off the end of `$user[]` and `$post[]` in the `while` lines.

Comment: @Jessie Ok the data displays on the browser, but it doesn't display on  the React Native app. Could it be a JSON problem?

Comment: I don't have any experience with React so I can't help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php

//$conn = ... connect to database

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE username = '$username'";
$usql = "SELECT * FROM user_images  WHERE username = '$username'";

$queryTableOne = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryTableTwo = mysqli_query($conn, $usql);

$json = mysqli_fetch_array($queryTableOne, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$json2 = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryTableTwo)) {
    $json2[] = array(
        'your_field1' => $row["your_field1"],
        'your_field2' => $row["your_field2"],
        'your_field3' => $row["your_field3"],
        //...etc
    );
}

$json['user_images'] = $json2;
echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911533/two-queries-mysql-in-one-object-json)

---

But using `JOIN` is a better way.